Use of colour with shirt in sports team
I'm a litle confused by the construction of colour + shirt. What does "shirt" mean in this context?

Newcastle United vs Manchester City
Jacob Murphy has seen plenty of
the ball on the right and he's always looking to get a cross in. He
releases it early this time, which is cut out before it can reach a
black and white shirt.
Everton 0-0 Spurs (24 mins)                                           Big chance for Spurs. White shirts
flood forward, and Sergio Reguilon dinks a fine cross across the
penalty area, that opposite wing-back Emerson Royal charges onto and
heads just over. Shades of Marcos Alonso and Victor Moses in that
move.


It's metonymy. In metonymy, a word that is associated with something is used to refer to that thing (as when crown is used to mean "king" or "queen").

Also: yellow jersey.

In the Newcastle game, a black and white shirt refers to a Newcastle player.  Jacob Murphy tried to get a cross in to one of them, but the cross was intercepted.
In the Spurs game, 'Big chance for Spurs. White shirts flood forward' tells us that white shirts refers to the Spurs players.
Commentators sometimes use jersey colours to refer to the players.

HERE, shirt=player, black and white shirts are the players wearing those colors of shirt during the game.
white shirts=players wearing those colors during the game.
Go to youtube to see the games.
for example, below is a Newcastle player in a black and white shirt:

shirt colorshttps://shop.newcastleunited.com/?srsltid=AfmBOooB8pGhp6dOwmOhly390HM8ygrexY_llgXn0wwZ8C8mDRXbKz6G
But be careful as some teams have official colors and they may or may not be wearing shirts with those colors during a game.

Is this term called synecdoche, using one part to refer to the whole?

No, it's just a metaphor. It substitutes for the word [team name] player.

Thanks a lot, Lambie. That's clear now.

It's also a kind of metonym.

@Barmar A metaphor is a metonym. Her eyes are diamonds.

@Lambie A metonym is when you use a metaphor as a name for the thing. Like "The White House issued a proclamation".

@Barmar Please don't give me English lessons. Thanks.

And note this might be a UK or soccer (football outside the US) thing, I cannot recall ever hearing this construction in the context of a US baseball or American football game.

@SoronelHaetir This is football UK (i.e. soccer). Those teams are British. There is no "might be."

@Shakila So why aren't you closing these questions? This is a valid answer.
